# can't find dnd component with multi drag and drag all selected items

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, multi-drag

can't find a dnd component under my requirement
https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.app/?path=/story/multi-drag--pattern
this component is perfect, but when dragging, I need all the elements to be selected, and not just one, as here
https://nikhilbaradwaj.github.io/ReactMultiDnD/
maybe someone saw such a solution?

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

No libraries implements this out of the box. Such functionality should be implemented manually.